# Where does the suffix "-etum" come from?

Tags: suffixes

I noticed recently that most (but not all) [Latin words ending in *-etum*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?type=end&lookup=etum&lang=la) have something to do with a cluster of vegetation. An obvious example derived into English is an "arboretum."

Where does "-etum" come from? Was it considered a productive suffix? Extra points if you can find a classical source that mentions the suffix!

Answer (score 6):

*Allen & Greenough* lists *-etum*/*-tum* under the heading 'Nouns with Adjective Suffixes' (section 254). It notes that the suffix denotes '*place* of a thing, especially with names of trees and plants to designate where these *grow*.'

The examples provided are:

- *quercetum*, 'oak grove'
- *olivetum*, 'olive grove'
- *salictum*, 'a willow thicket'
- *Argiletum*, 'The Clay Pit' (from *argilla*, 'clay')

Plus, you've already mentioned *arboretum*. I've also seen *rosetum* and *fruticetum*, and the corresponding section in *Gildersleeve & Lodge* (181) offers *myrtetum* and *virgultum*. So, given the somewhat limited area of applicability, the suffix seems to be reasonably productive.

In A&G, comparison is made to the suffixes *-atus* and *-utus*, and there's a reference to the following note from section 246:

> NOTE. — -atus, -itus, -utus, imply reference to an imaginary verb-stem: -tus is added directly to nouns without any such reference.

I can't help wondering whether there's some original relationship to the *-esc* suffix/infix that has to do with beginning/growing/becoming. There is in fact a verb *arborescere*, 'to grow into a tree.' Perhaps *arboretum* originally meant '(a place where) there has been growing into trees,' as a sort of impersonal passive. There's also a verb *fruticesco*, 'to put forth shoots, become bushy'; so *fruticetum* could likewise denote a place where this action has occurred. Other words, where no verb is attested, could easily have been formed by analogy. This is just conjecture, of course, and not a 'proper' answer.

Answer (score 4):

Buck, Comparative grammar p. 335, writes that Latin -ētum is “originally from verb stems in ē, as in acētum ‘vinegar’ (acēscō ‘turn sour’), but productive in nouns of place, especially place where a plant grows.”

de Vann derives acētum from aceō ‘be sour’, not from the inchoative acēscō; in any case the ē is part of the stem. It seems possible to me that the productive suffix -ētum was simply extracted from acētum.